# Why does not seekg(0) clear the eof state of stream?

Tags: c++, iostream

I would like to know if and why `seekg(0)` is not supposed to clear the `eofbit` of a stream.
I am in a point where I have already read all the stream, thus `EOF` has been reached (but no `failbit` is set yet) and want to go back with `seekg()` to a valid position and read some chars again. In this case `seekg(0)` seems "to work" with the `eofbit` set, but as soon as I try to read from the stream, the failbit is set. Is this logic, correct or is my implementation bad? Am I supposed to recognize this case and clear the eofbit manually (if the failbit is not set)?

EDIT:

The following program provided by a reader gives different results in my implementation ( mingw32-c++.exe (TDM-2 mingw32) 4.4.1 ):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
        std::istringstream foo("AAA");
        std::string a;
        foo >> a;
        std::cout << foo.eof() << " " << foo.fail() << std::endl; // 1 0
        foo.seekg(0);
        std::cout << foo.eof() << " " << foo.fail() << std::endl; // 0 0
        foo >> a;
        std::cout << foo.eof() << " " << foo.fail() << std::endl; // 1 0
        foo >> a;
        std::cout << foo.eof() << " " << foo.fail() << std::endl; // 1 1
}
```

The comments above are from the user who tried that program in his implementation. I obtain these results:

```
1 0
1 0
1 1
1 1
```

Comment: Yes, you have to manually reset the state of the stream.

Comment: @Martin: Seems to be the old standard vs new standard issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the **new** standard `clear()` is supposed to reset the `eofbit` (§ 27.7.2.3):

> `basic_istream<charT,traits>& seekg(pos_type pos);`
>
> *Effects:* Behaves as an unformatted input function ..., except that the function ﬁrst clears `eofbit` ...

But in the **old** standard (§ 27.6.1.3) there is no mention of clearing the `eofbit`!

And a simple test:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
        std::istringstream foo("AAA");
        std::string a;
        foo >> a;
        std::cout << foo.eof() << " " << foo.fail() << std::endl; // 1 0
        foo.seekg(0);
        std::cout << foo.eof() << " " << foo.fail() << std::endl; // 0 0
        foo >> a;
        std::cout << foo.eof() << " " << foo.fail() << std::endl; // 1 0
        foo >> a;
        std::cout << foo.eof() << " " << foo.fail() << std::endl; // 1 1
}
```

Comment: after your first foo.seekg(0), the eofbit is cleared in your example, while it's still up in my implementation. Which was why I was asking something strange might happen. Your program gives 1 0, 1 0, 1 1, 1 1

Comment: @Martin: Good point. Which compiler and what environment? I get the posted results with: `clang 3.1`, `gcc 4.7.0` and `gcc 4.6.3` (with and without `-std=c++0x`). However with `VS2010` I get same the same result as you.

Comment: A bit oldish [document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146445) from Microsoft may shed some light on the issue. **Status:** _This behavior is by design._ And the standard...?

Comment: the compiler is the gcc port to Windows, MinGW, the ones which comes with Code::Block IDE executable for Windows: mingw32-c++.exe (TDM-2 mingw32) 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Why not just manually clear() the stream then go back once the eofbit has been set? EOF has been reached, why should seekg clear it automatically? Doing that would seem to cause more problems.