# After reading from fstream, why does it seem to need its goodbit clearing before writing to it?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

Here is an example to illustrate the question:

```
// Create/truncate file and save '1'
const string NAME = "example.txt";
fstream file(NAME.c_str(), ios::out | ios::trunc);
file << '1';
file.close();

// Re-open file and output its only line
file.open(NAME.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
string text;
getline(file, text);
cout << "Read \"" << text << "\"" << endl;
// OUTPUTS: Read "1"

// (Try to) Append '2'
file << '2';
file.seekg(0);
getline(file, text);
cout << "Read \"" << text << "\"" << endl;
// OUTPUTS: Read "1"

// (Try to) Append '3'
file.clear(ios::goodbit); /*** SHOULD IT BE NECESSARY TO CLEAR THIS FLAG? ***/
file << '3';
file.seekg(0);
getline(file, text);
cout << "Read \"" << text << "\"" << endl;
// OUTPUTS: Read "13"
```

I feel a little uneasy about including a line of code that I don't really understand!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`goodbit` isn't a bit you can clear, it's the state of not having any error state flag bits set.  In a typical implementation of `ios`,

```
struct ios {
  enum iostate {
    goodbit = 0,
    badbit  = 0x1,
    failbit = 0x2,
    eofbit  = 0x4,
  };
};
```

The reason that you need to clear the error state flags is that after `getline` the eofbit is set so the `<<` operator has no effect.  You can verify this by printing out the error state:

```
cout << file.rdstate();
```

Answer (score 2):

`getline` sets the `eofbit` because it doesn't find the delimiter (newline). So there's certainly a flag set on the stream. `ios::goodbit` isn't really a bit, it means "all flags clear", so it's the eofbit you're clearing.

I'd be inclined to trust your implementation to respond correctly to that bit when writing, so if it tells you that the write fails then I more or less believe it. Someone will probably do the standards-diving to find the relevant text.

[Why does not seekg(0) clear the eof state of stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141075/why-does-not-seekg0-clear-the-eof-state-of-stream) says there's a difference between C++03 and C++11. In C++11, your call to `seekg` clears the `eofbit`, so because the write failed you read back `"1"`. In C++03, your call to `seekg` does not clear the `eofbit`, so the second read fails and `text` just happens to still contain `"1"` from before.

It's almost always incorrect to use `<<` or `>>` without checking the state of the stream immediately afterwards:

```
if (file << '2') {
    // seekg and so on to confirm what is in the file
} else {
    std::cout << "write failed" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks (and +1) for the swift response. Don't worry about the lack of state-checking, my production code includes this! I have accepted ecatmur's answer because I feel the struct example explains the flags very effectively.

Answer (score 0):

> getline(file, text);

Your file doesn't have a newline, so this reads up to the end of the file and sets `eofbit`

After that you can't read or write any more until your clear the `eofbit`